# Trying to answer descriptive statistics questions comparing groups in r using tidyverse and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, tidyverse, categorical-data

My data looks like this:

```
        ID       Date                                          Reduction     Collected Provided         Freq Gender
1   AAA016000 2018-04-10                                           0              0              7        1   <NA>
2   AAA059717 2017-03-21                                           1              0             45       10 Female
3   AAA059717 2017-04-22                                           0              0             10       10 Female
4   AAA059717 2017-05-09                                           0              0             10        2 Female
5   AAA059717 2017-06-09                                           1              0             40        6 Female
6   AAA059717 2018-07-03                                          NA            180            200       35 Female
7   AAA059717 2018-09-26                                          NA             10             30       15 Female
8   AAA059717 2018-09-26                                           1             NA             NA       NA Female
9   AAA059717 2018-10-12                                          NA              0             20        3 Female
10  AAA059717 2018-11-07                                          NA             30             50       20 Female
11  AAA059717 2018-11-07                                           0             NA             NA       NA Female
12  AAA059717 2018-11-08                                          NA              2             20       10 Female

'data.frame':   190122 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ ID                                         : chr  "AAA016000" "AAA059717" "AAA059717" "AAA059717" ...
 $ Date                                       : Date, format: "2018-04-10" "2017-03-21" "2017-04-22" "2017-05-09" ...
 $ Reduction                                  : num  0 1 0 0 1 NA NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ Collected                                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 180 10 NA 0 30 ...
 $ Provided                                   : num  7 45 10 10 40 200 30 NA 20 50 ...
 $ Freq                                       : num  1 10 10 2 6 35 15 NA 3 20 ...
 $ Gender                                     : chr  NA "Female" "Female" "Female" ...
```

To find out if " Do females have more Collected than males?" I tried doing this:

```
df_tidy <- df %>%
  group_by(df$Gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(sum_collected = sum(df$Collected), na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = df$Gender, y = sum_collected)) + 
  geom_col()
```

But got this error?:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Why? How do i fix this and get a simple discriplive table to answer my question that looks kinda like this:

```
Gender   sum_collected
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Female               20
2 Male                 10
```

And when i try to find out if higher freq also has higher Provided, i did this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Freq, y = Provided)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

But the graph doesn't look right??
[image: Graph]

and lastly, if Provided is more frequent if Freq is over 10?
Thank you for your response, I apreciate it.

Comment: Just remove the `df$` insdie the functions i.e. `f_tidy <- df %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(sum_collected = sum(Collected), na.rm = TRUE)` and then use `Gender` instead of `df$` in `aes`.  Reason is that `df$` will extract the whole column and not the values within the group

Comment: Great, that worked thankS! What about the second two parts??